# Magento remove div by local.xml

Tags: magento

I know that I can remove blocks by commands, but is one thing more correct, than the other? 
Also, would I somehow be able to remove a .div class instead of a block? so that I can remove a .div from a specific page?

Heres the examples of the snippets I know of, to remove blocks.

```
<remove name="name_name"></remove>
<action method="unsetChild"><name>name.name</name></action>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Remove` - remove block from any level, example block `AAA` is child of the block `left` that is child of the block `content` then I can remove it at top level of page layout:

```
<xxx_index_index>
  <remove name="AAA" />
  ....
```

`unsetChild` we can use only within parent of the target block, example if I have this layout:

```
<default>
  <reference name="content">
    <block name="BBB" ... />
```

Then I can remove BBB with method `unsetChild`

```
<yyy_index_index>
  <reference name="content">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>BBB</name></action>
```

Comment: Great information, could one of these methods also be applied to cms blocks?

Comment: Mean you under the "cms blocks" system layout blocks like `<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">`? Yes, of course, you can use these methods to any layout blocks without exception. These methods also could be used within CMS Pages (Admin panel -> CMS -> Pages -> tab "Design").

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't remove a `div` HTML element unless there is a block comprised of this element and defined in the layout configuration. You can then remove that block and with it the desired div.

There are no provisions to remove HTML elements by using the Magento Layout settings.

You can, however, use layout config to include a javascript file that employs CSS selectors to remove div elements you want.